# Focus with order editTexts in listview

Tags: android, listview, barcode-scanner

My app is barcodeReader which user read to barcodeID set it Textview and he can enter the number of product in editText.I implement in listview which include textview and editText. When user scan to barcodeNumber, i set to it on textView and but i want after set to text automatically focus the edit text in order .How can i do that?

> Edit!!
>   I already add to request focus on  but always focus on 1. editText and when 2. Barcode scanned 1.editText value again take "0";

This is my listView;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="number">
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my adapter;

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<Model> productList;
Activity activity;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Model> productList) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return productList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView ID;
    EditText Quantity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID);
        holder.Quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity);;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Model item = productList.get(position);
    holder.ID.setText(item.getID().toString());
    holder.Quantity(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

And here is the Activity;

```
public class BarcodeReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnBarcodeReader;

EditText Quantity;
private ArrayList<Model> mlist;
Model item;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcodereader);

    mlist= new ArrayList<Model>();
    ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, mlist);
    QuantityRowID = findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnBarcodeReader =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBarcodeReader);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    final Activity activity = this;

    btnBarcodeReader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            populateList(result.getContents());

        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        QuantityRowID.requestFocus();
        int val = Integer.parseInt( QuantityRowID.getText().toString() );
        item.Quantity=val;
        QuantityRowID.setText(val);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void populateList(String ID){
    item = new Model(ID,0);
    mlist.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

Comment: After *setText* to *Text View* try to do *Quantity.requestFocus();*.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply set `request focus` on your EditText after setting all view like

```
//your other view like textview and imageview if you have
Quantity.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
    edittextbox.requestFocus();
```

and xml code..

```
<EditText ...>
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I edit my question; i already add to requestFocus() but it is not woking.

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter getView() method write this

```
 holder.ID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          holder.Quantity.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, it will forcefully show the keyboard to targeted editText.

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyboard.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void populateList(String ID){
    item = new Model(ID,0);
    mlist.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(mlist.size() - 1);
    LinearLayout childView = (LinearLayout)listView.getChildAt(listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    EditText quantity = (EditText)childView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
    quantity.requestFocus();
}
```

Hope it helps!!